# Log scale for matplotlib colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, julia

I am using pyplot (Julia version of matplotlib) to do plotting in Julia. I am making a 2D color plot like this one, where the values may be positive or negative:

[image]

I would like the colorbar axis to be logarithmic, i.e the values should be indicated for $100,200$ as $10^2$, $2*10^2$, and similarly for the negative values:$-10^2,-2*10^2$, etc. Actually it's ok if only the powers of 10 and their negatives are indicated by numbers, with 10 tick marks in between two powers of 10.

Comment: matplotlib has the concept of `LogNorm` which will carry over to the colorbar axes.

Comment: See the official [reference](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html).